# Parsing a user defined format?

Tags: c++, parsing, boost

I love the way of how [`Boost property_tree`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/property_tree.html) parsing certain types of files. But my file is kind of different

```
/*--------------------------------*- C++ -*----------------------------------*\
| WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW |
\*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
INFORMATION
{
    version     2.0;
    format      ascii;
}
// * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //

school
{
    "(boys|girls)"
    {
        hair red;
        legs short;
        nose long;
        mood good;
    }

    workers
    {
        hair green;
        legs long;
        nose abnormal;
        mood bad;
    }
}

// ************************************************************************* //
```

I hope it can be used in this way

```
string myMood = pt.get<std::string>("school.boys.mood");
cout<< "\tmyMood is = " << myMood << endl;
```

Which is very clean and straightforward.

But it seems currently the boost ptree INFO parser cannot handle comments and `"(boys|girls)"` type.

Any solution?

Comment: None that I see. Boost property_tree is not meant to handle alternatives.

Comment: Hmm, are you from boost committee? I want to write my codes using `Boost property_tree`. But I am not sure are they going to be kept or removed in the future? Or I'd better not using it?

Comment: No affiliation, just using Boost in various projects myself. Generally speaking, however, Boost is the next best thing to the standard library. I've yet to experience a component of Boost being dropped.

Comment: OOPS, then there is risk here. I am afraid `Boost property_tree` will be knocked off by `Boost Spirit` eventually...I'd better write a parser my own.

Comment: I really don't think so. They have *very* different purposes. `property_tree` is for rather base storage of key - value pairs and config file reading. Boost.Spirit is a full-blown parser / lexer solution - and requires quite some up-front work before you can read in your first file.